# RESTful route add new post method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes

My routes file looks like this one with my new restful post action:

```
resources :projects do
       post 'addpartner'
end
```

And in my view:

```
<%= link_to '[Add]', project_addpartner_url(@project,partner) ,
    confirm: 'Are you sure?',
    method: :post %>
```

Now the problem is project_addpartner_url generates the path with the default formatting. For my case it is something like:

```
/projects/1/addpartner.16
```

But my expected formatting is something like:

```
/projects/1/addpartner/16
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your link is setup as a GET methods, that's why you get

```
/projects/1/addpartner.16
```

But the way you want is seems like GET

```
/projects/1/addpartner/16
```

So try changing your link as

```
<%= link_to '[Add]', project_addpartner_url(@project,partner) ,
    confirm: 'Are you sure?',
    method: :get %>
```

But normally add/update/delete should be POST methods.

Comment: i tried with the get method ... but it's the same :( ... 
i think i needs to change something in my routing :S

Answer (score 1):

Try use another route, like:

```
resources :projects do
 member do
  post 'addpartner'
 end
end
```

Or, maybe:

```
resources :projects do
 collection do
  post 'addpartner'
 end
end
```